# Unable to install CiviCRM 4.7 on Wordpress 4.4.1

Tags: wordpress, installation, 4.7

Environment:

PHP Version 5.6.15

Apache 2.4.17

MySQL 5.6.27

Windows 10

Wordpress Plugins Active: 
Exclude Pages from Navigation, Ninja Forms, Ninja Forms - Layout Master

When attempting to install CiviCRM on my local dev platform described above, I am following the instructions as detailed at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5

Everything is fine until I click the "Check Requirements and Install CiviCRM" button - a spinner briefly appears next to it before the frame on the admin page goes blank (menu and toolbar remain) and the entire page appears to be attempting to refresh. Then after a few minutes of loading I am left with a URL ending `wp-admin/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm&reset=1` - and a white screen.

If I navigate back to my admin console and attempt to go into the CiviCRM plugin I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation
>   canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking
>   installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in
>   (*MyWordpressHomeFolder*)\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\InstallationCanary.php on line 53

I have tried manually deleting the civicrm_install_canary table but that does not resolve the issue...

Comment: I see the OS is Windows 10.   Did you build the stack (Apache, PHP, MySQL) by hand or are you using XAMP or something similiar?

Answer (score 1):

First try to increase the max_execution_time of your server in php.ini file. As the post installation process may take time long enough that time out occurs.

Also you can find more about the Installation Canary [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/what-is-the-installation-canary).

Hope this helps.