# CiviCRM Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary

Tags: wordpress, installation

If you can advise or solve my problem – please answer

I trying to install CiviCRM 4.7.14 for wordpress 4.7 on windows machine, all steps of installation based on official CiviCRM installation guide.
After step where i setup database connection and click install i got at left panel icon civicrm how it must be, 
but after click on this button I got error about non correct path in civicrm.settings.php, after fixing double slashes to single slashes “/” in this file and update page I got next error that I can’t solve

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\InstallationCanary.php on line 53

All requirements are fine and I do not got any warning or errors at step with install.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This error means something went wrong in the installation procedure. You can find more information about the Installation Canary at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/what-is-the-installation-canary . Can you try to drop and recreate the databases to start with a clean slate?

Comment: @Kainuk yes i tryed three times, and got this error three times. Wordpress installed from blank and civicrm too, did not got any problems about requirements or something, all entires green.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using (PHP 7 is still very new for CiviCRM)?

Comment: @Kainuk PHP Version 5.6

Comment: @Kainuk now i have next error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException' with message 'Cannot rename "D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\templates_c\CacDFB0.tmp" to "D:/home/site/wwwroot/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c//CachedCiviContainer.408b9887eb68e85cf1131bc6d5ded777.php".'"

Comment: Hi @Kukin, why gives the question the path C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\  and your error  D:/home/site/wwwroot/wp-content? I did just an installation on Windows, that works. I will set my configuration in the answer. Maybe you spot a difference, which leads to a solution.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: i restore path to the double slashes and have same error, well i will try again with your steps

Answer (score 2):

I just did an installation on my Windows Laptop, and it worked. I describe below my configuration. Maybe it leads to a working configuration on your system.

1. I downloaded and installed the *xampp-win32-5.6.28-0-VC11-installer* installer from [ApacheFriends](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). The installation decides for the default home *C:\xampp*.
2. After the installation, the Xampp control panel starts. I start Apache and MySQL.
3. I open the shell to create the databases (I am more at my ease with Unix). I create the databases with the following commands:

   ```
   mysql -u root

   create database wp character set utf8;
   create database civi character set utf8;
   grant all on wp.* to wpuser@localhost identified by 'wppwd';
   grant all on civi.* to civiuser@localhost identified by 'civipwd';
   flush privileges;
   ```
4. I install WordPress by unzipping the download in the `C:\xampp\htdocs` directory. I remove all other files (to keep the installation clean).
5. I do the WordPress configuration according to the documentation. (database wp, user wpuser, password wppassword).
6. I unzip the CiviCRM (*civicrm-4.7.14-wordpress.zip*) in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins`.
7. Now I activate the CiviCRM in the plugins menu and complete the installation with the *Almost Ready* invitation. (database civi, user civiuser, password civipwd).
8. Installation completes without problems.

The `civicrm.settings.php` file is generated in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\uploads\civicrm`. In the file is a mix of forward slashes and backslashes, but CiviCRM does not seem to bother. For example:

```
$civicrm_root = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs/wp-content/plugins\\civicrm\\civicrm\\';
if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
 define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs/wp-content/uploads\\civicrm\\templates_c\\');
}
```

Comment: for me it return Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException' with message 'Cannot rename "D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\templates_c\Cac1698.tmp" to "D:\home\site\wwwroot/wp-content/uploads\civicrm\templates_c\/CachedCiviContainer.408b9887eb68e85cf1131bc6d5ded777.php"