# Error when installing civicrm-4.7.29-drupal on Drupal-7.56

Tags: drupal, database, installation

when I install civicrm-4.7.29-drupal on Drupal-7.56 just using one database for drupal an civicrm the installation runs perfectly without any errors.
If I use two databases for drupal and civicrm I get the following error message:
CRM_Core_Exception: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. in Civi\Core\InstallationCanary::check() (line 53 of /[my website]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php).
What did I do wrong? Or is it a bug?
Best,
Frank

Comment: Hope this might be useful https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15594/what-is-the-installation-canary

Comment: Dear Pradeep, many thanks. When I used two new "virgin" databases it worked perfectly. Maybe the problem arose of the fact that I accidentially installed CiviCRM in the drupal database and started all over again.

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this error a few weeks ago and it indicates that you are trying to install CiviCXM into a drupal environment which already contains an installed version of CiviCRM.